# Was is the idiomatic way to define partial functions in Perl?

Tags: perl, idioms

What is the most common/idiomatic way to define partial functions in Perl, that is functions that are not defined on all inputs. For example, in Haskell we have

```hs
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead (x:xs) = Just x
```

in C we have

```c
int factorial(int n) {
     assert(n >= 0);
     int result = 1;
     while (n) result *= n--;
     return result;
}
```

or

```c
int factorial(int n) {
     if (n < 0) return -1;
     int result = 1;
     while (n) result *= n--;
     return result;
}
```

I would rather not import a CPAN module.

Comment: Consider whether to return `undef` when the result is undefined.  I'm not sure there's a standard convention, but returning `-1` for the factorial would work.  The head of an empty list might return `undef` effectively.  Etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't think of undef, that makes sense, what I was using is `die "factorial($n) is undefined" if $n < 0 or $n != int($n);`

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Re "*The head of an empty list might return `undef` effectively.*", Only if the list can't contain `undef`. In that situation, you could return nothing at all instead of `undef`.  For example, the following loops until the iterator returns nothing: `while ( my ( $element ) = $iter->() ) { ... }` Returning a false value (such as `undef`, the number `0` or the string `0`) will not end it.

Comment: @ikegami — yes, it depends a lot on the nature of the list.  There are other caveats not mentioned too, neither in my original comment nor in this addendum to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like in C, you can return from the middle of Perl subs.

```perl
sub factorial {
   my $n = shift;

   return -1 if $n < 0;

   my $acc = 1;
   $acc *= $_ for 2 .. $n;
   return $acc;
}
```

Assertion-style:

```perl
sub factorial {
   my $n = shift;

   $n >= 0
      or return -1;

   my $acc = 1;
   $acc *= $_ for 2 .. $n;
   return $acc;
}
```

If I were to use `return` here, I'd probably return `undef` rather than `-1`. Any misuse of this returned value should be noisy.

But I would more likely throw an exception (using [`croak`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp)) for invalid inputs.

---

A side note on how to check for different return values.

| `if` condition | `return false;` `return 0;` `return "";` `return "0";` | `return undef;` | `return;` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `my $x = f()` | False condition | False condition | False condition |
| `defined( my $x = f() )` | True condition | False condition | False condition |
| `my ( $x ) = f()` | True condition | True condition | False condition |